# Difference between getModel('catalog/product') and getSingleton('catalog/product')

Tags: magento-1.7

I have seen both function in Magento Files,

What is deference between both function. and also where I use one of them function.

Which is best to load Product Collection.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756753/magento-getsingleton-vs-getmodel-issue

Comment: http://shahkeyul.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/difference-between-magegetsingleton-and-magegetmodel-in-magento/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Amit for the great links, but because we don't have the answer here yet, we can not close the questions a duplicate, so here is the answer:

Magento wants to introduce with `Mage::getSingleton()` the [Singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). If I understand it correctly it is not exactly a singleton, because `Mage` takes care of only ONE instance. But fact is, if you are using Mage::getSingleton, you get the same object over and over again throughout all your code.

`Mage::getModel()` is just a standard factory and returns a newly created object of whatever type

So depending on you want to write to the same or a different object, you use either `getSingleton` or `getModel`